# Does this image represent a molecule?

Tags: electrochemistry

[image: Molecule Image?]

PLease help me to define this,
Thank you,
Bruce

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Thanks, it has been a few years since college chemistry and was wondering if this illustration fit in today's chemical world. I took an electrical and process control engineering path in my career and have seen changes in electrical representation since I first started. This is supposed to be a crop circle but looks to me like someone dabbling with atomic representation. Again, thank you, first time asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of drawing/representing molecules:

**Lewis Dot**: It shows bonding and non-bonding electrons. 2D

**Bond-Line Notation**: Like Lewis Dot but is simplified. C and H are shown as lines. It simplifies large structures to highlights important atoms, bonds, and groups that could react. 2D

**Ball and Stick**: It's a three-dimensional arrangement of atoms and bonds. 3D

**Space Fill**: The "fat" version of Ball and Stick. Shows three-dimensional arrangement as well as size relationships between atoms. 3D

The picture shown would probably be a 2D imprint of a Ball and Stick model.

However, it is **JUST A CROP CIRCLE**.

If you want to overextend it try using ChemSpider to draw something similar and see if you get any hits.

Comment: Thank you folks! Your input is what I am looking for! It has been too many years since my training; my career in the electrical world makes me aware of differences in schematic representation over just a period of 30+ years! Yes, this picture is just a crop circle but I assume the author of it was playing with his chemical passion. I wouldn't do this in another's field and hope if someone tried this in my field my bull and donkey would chase them out!! I am still interested in if this is a compound representation or just someone playing. Thank you for being helpful to an old guy!